# Venn diagram for indepenent events

Tags: probability

In a Venn diagram, are two events represented as two disjunctive(non-intersecting) areas ?
This in turn means that for two independent events X,Y the probability of `P(X|Y) = 0` since the realization of Y means that X cannot be realized anymore, right ?

Then, why do people take the approach of showing that `P(X|Y) = P(X)` or that `P(X & Y) = P(X) * P(Y)` in order to prove that X and Y are independent? Why not show that `P(X|Y) = 0` ? It's more intuitive !

Comment: It's a different notion. Events are independent if knowledge of one cannot be used to predict the other. With your notion, the events of a bag of rice falling from a shelf in China and you catching the flu while travelling to Norway would *not* be independent!

Comment: You're confused. If $P(X \mid Y) = 0$ (or, equivalently, your Venn diagram condition holds), this means that $X$ and $Y$ are *mutually-exclusive*, not independent. These are two completely different notions.

Comment: I don't think "disjunctive" is the correct word. Given any two events $X,Y$, we say that $X$ and $Y$ are **disjoint** (or **mutually exclusive**) iff $P(X \text{ and } Y) = 0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It's still not very clear to me why it's so obvious that there is no connection between the intersection of two events in a Venn diagram and their independence. If, indeed, there is no connection, why is P(X|Y) = P(X intersected Y)/P(Y)

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of independence, that $P(X|Y)=0$, is not the definition of independence used in probability. In fact, $P(X|Y)=0$ implies **dependence**, since the outcome of $Y$ influences (that is, completely inhibits) $X$.

What you're describing is mutual exclusivity.

When two outcomes are mutually exclusive, they are counted as two distinct possible outcomes of the same event. (e.g. a coin toss can be heads or tails. Heads or tails is two possible outcomes of one event: a single coin toss).

One the other hand, when we speak of two events being *independent*, we count these as two separate outcomes of two separate events (e.g. when tossing two coins, the outcome of either coin toss is independent of the other).

Comment: :) I think that if you hadn't edited the answer, it would've been better. "Heads or tails is two possible outcomes of one event: a single coin toss". You mean experiment instead of event. The same in the last paragraph which I don't really understand. 
Anyway, I suppose there is no way of graphically representing two independent events, or at least not by using a Venn diagram, right ?

Comment: @Razvan Generally when writing probabilities as a Venn diagram (at least this was how I was taught), you always put an intersection between the events, and just write the probability in each section (each section being $A$, $B$, and $A\land{B}$). This still works even if the events are independent.

Comment: It's still not very clear to me why it's so obvious that there is no connection between the intersection of two events in a Venn diagram and their independence. If, indeed, there is no connection, why is P(X|Y) = P(X intersected Y)/P(Y)

Comment: @Razvan There is a connection. You write $P(X)$ into one section, $P(Y)$ into the other, and $P(X\land{Y})$ in the intersection between them. The only difference the independence makes is the **values** that you will write in.

Answer (score 0):

As Ataraxia said, P(X|Y)=0 implies dependence.

Let's take an example. 
Suppose you roll an unbiased dice. Events possible are {1,2,3,4,5,6}. 
Here, P(Getting 1|Getting 2)=0 because only one can happen at a time. This makes the events mutually- exclusive.

Now, say, I am also tossing a coin with the dice. Intuitively, its an *independent* event in the sense that outcome of one is not affecting the other. 
P(Getting '1' on dice *and* Getting head on coin) = P(Getting '1' on dice) * P(Getting head on coin). **Note that the sample space of the independent events is different, unlike dependent events**.

Hope this helps your understanding.